# <s:if> tag is not working

Tags: java, struts2

I am having trouble with the Struts 2 `<s:if>`/`<s:else>` tags–the condition is not matching. It is always going to else block.

I have a variable subMenu in my action with setters and getters. I set the variable to "1" in my action.

I have tried each of the syntaxes below:

```
<s:if test="%{#subMenu == \"1\"}">
  This is Submenu 1
 </s:if>

 <s:if test="subMenu == '1'">
   You have selected 1. 
 </s:if>

 <s:if test="%{#subMenu == '1'}">
   This is Submenu 1
 </s:if>

 <s:if test="%{subMenu == '1'}">
   This is Submenu 1
 </s:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

If `subMenu` is a `String` as the tests imply, use double-quotes, otherwise the immediate value will be interpreted as a `char` (not `String`) because it's a single character in single quotes.

```
<s:if test='%{subMenu == "1"}'>
  This is Submenu 1
</s:if>
```

Note that I've flipped which quotes are used where. This is just how OGNL works.

Alternatives include using an actual integer, or having an easier-to-reason-about system beyond "1", "2", "3", etc. and using contextually-meaningful names instead of making people think about it.

Answer (score 1):

here could be the solution.
if the result of your action is "plain" and subMenu is type "string", which means, it is a page

```
<s:if test="subMenu == '1'">test</s:if>
```

should work.

here is the suggestion.

1. try print "subMenu" first to check, if the variable not null by using:

   ```
   <s:property value="subMenu"/>
   ```
2. check your action class, if your result is not *.jsp, but *.action, you will lose your variable, try add your variable as parameter like this:

   ```
   <result name="success">
       <param name="subMenu">${subMenu}</param>
       <param name="location">*.action</param>
       ...
   </result>
   ```

Comment: It won't, because of how OGNL parses single-character entities surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi Dave, actually i use 'string' myself in my strut2 project, and it works well. it does not mean to surround a char, but to differ with " ".

Comment: OGNL treats a single character in single quotes as a character, not a string--that's why the OP's comparison fails. I can show you the running code showing the difference, and the OGNL docs explaining it, if necessary.

Comment: @DaveNewton that would be very nice. and thank you very much, if you can show me this. because i'm really using <s:if test="variable == 'test'">OK</s:if> on running project. :-)

Comment: And there's no reason you couldn't--that's not a single-character in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For Single characters struts if comparison didnt work.Easy solution is try using a string instead of a single char